# Uniqueness of Schur covering groups for non-perfect groups

Tags: gr.group-theory

Perfect group are known to have a unique (up to isomorphism) Schur covering group. But so can some non-perfect groups, the alternating group $A_4$ being an example. Is there a condition weaker than perfectness  (perhaps even a criterion) that guarantees uniqueness of the Schur covering group?

In particular, is the following true:

**Conjecture.** Let $G$ be a finite group such that $|M(G)|$ is coprime to $|G/G'|$. Then the Schur covering group of $G$ is unique.

*Remark.* $M(G)$ is the Schur multiplier of $G$.

Comment: I think your conjecture follows from the Universal Coefficient Theorem because ${\rm Hom}(G/G',M(G)) = 0$ in that situation.

Comment: Another example of a non-perfect group with unique Schur covering group, which is not covered by your conjecture, is $S_6$. This is somehow connected with the outer automorphism of $S_6$. For $n \ge 4$ and $n \ne 6$ there are two isomorphism types of covering groups of $S_n$.

Comment: @Derek If $|M(G)|$ is coprime to $|G/G'|$, The Universal Coefficient Theorem for Cohomology implies $H^2(G,M(G))\cong \mathrm{End}(M(G))$. But it is not clear which elements of  $H^2(G,M(G))$ correspond to Schur covering groups.

Comment: It is the isomorphisms of $M(G)$ that correspond to Schur Covering groups - they are essentially just renamings of the elements of $M(G)$, so they are all isomorphic as groups.